# Laravel: There are no commands defined in the "ab" namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have to publish a database in my laravel 4 app from another package. So I ran this command:

> php artisan ab:install

It says

> [InvalidArgumentException]                               There are no
>   commands defined in the "ab" namespace.

I tried running `composer dump-autoload` and also tried `php artisan optimize`.
Composer still throws the InvalidArgumentException.

**EDIT**

I had missed adding the service provider and registering the alias in the app.php file. Doing so fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missed adding the service provider and registering the alias in the app.php file. Doing so fixed this issue.

I had to add `'Jenssegers\AB\TesterServiceProvider',` and `'AB => 'Jenssegers\AB\Facades\AB',`

to the `app/config/app.php`

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update composer with json file. Add the following code in json

```
"jenssegers/ab": "1.*"
```

Then save . Open command prompt. run composer update

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this wasn't the issue! Also, the package doesnt have a 1.* release. The latest one is 0.2.0